# boost::python access struct within struct

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have two structs:

```
struct A {
  float x,y;
};

struct B {
  A my_A;
};
```

I'm trying to set up bindings using boost::python to access `my_A`. So far, I have:

```
using boost::python;
scope in_B = class_<B>("B")
  .def_readwrite("my_A", B::my_A);

class_<A>("A")
  .def_readwrite("x", &A::x)
  .def_readwrite("y", &A::y);
```

but this does not allow me to retrieve `B.my_A.x`. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can you post the code that retrieves that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so @imreal's comment was spot on; my mistake was in accessing the data. I used `B.A.x` instead of `B.my_A.x`. That did it.